# How to build a black/white list for a file upload application?

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-4, whitelist, blacklist

I'm building a file management and upload web application right now and one of the things I've done little of so far is security against unsafe file types. I've been reading up online, trying to find a good way to build in security as this is something I've never done before. Black and White lists seem to be a blanket answer, but I don't know the best way to implement one. My application is built in ASP.net MVC 4 and the only security I have right now is:

```
 /// Check to see if the file isn't of the appropriate type

 if (extension == ".asp" || extension == ".exe" || extension == ".js")
 {
     ModelState.AddModelError("fileError", "That filetype is not permitted.");
 }
```

I've built upon that list to have the following disallowed:
`ani, asf, asp, avi, bas, bat, bin, chm, cmd, com, cpl, cur, eml, exe, hta, ico, js, jse, midi, mp3, mpa, mpe, mpeg, mpg, msc, msp, pcd, pif, rar, reg, scr, sct, vb, vbs, wma, wmf, wmv, wsc, wsf`

My current idea looks like this (semi-pseudocode, so yes, syntax isn't complete):

```
// in my model
public static bool IsInBlacklist(string extension)
{
    string[] blacklist = ani, asf, asp, avi, bas, bat, bin, chm, cmd, com, cpl, cur, eml, exe, hta, ico, js, jse, midi, mp3, mpa, mpe, mpeg, mpg, msc, msp, pcd, pif, rar, reg, scr, sct, vb, vbs, wma, wmf, wmv, wsc, wsf
    for int i = 0; i < blacklist.length(); i++
        if extension == blacklist[i]
            return true
        return false
}

// in my controller
if (IsInBlacklist(extension))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("fileError", "That filetype is not permitted.");
}
```

Is this a good approach? Bad approach? I know a more ideal way would be to check against the MIMEType (which I have access to), but I don't know how I would go about creating a black/white list around that.

Comment: Not a good idea, as for example, they could just name it `.exe.removethis` and that wouldn't go past the blacklists. Whitelists are better, but the MIMEType is even better than that.

Comment: Good point newStackExchangeInstance...I didn't think about that. I'll have to look into filtering on MIMEType.

Comment: In PHP I use a library that reads the file and reports it's type based upon the header contents. It's able to read over 100 file types, and from that I only allow the few I want. Everything else is rejected, but the filename is ignored.